# Clear Drop Down Based on UI response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a drop down that is the word submitted is selected a prompt pops up asking a question.
If the user clicks no or cancel I need that active cell to revert back to an empty drop down (like when you click delete and it resets the drop down)

Here is the code I do have:

```
    function sendMailEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var rData1 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,15).getValues();
  var lj1 = rData1[0][0];
  

  if (ss.getSheetName() == 'Design Doc Queue' &
    ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 6 &
    ss.getActiveCell().getValue() == "Submitted") {    
    var alertPromptText = '⚠️ Are you sure you want to submitt these drawings '+ lj1 +' for review? ';

    var promptResponse = ui.alert(alertPromptText, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO_CANCEL);

    if (promptResponse == ui.Button.YES) {

      // CHECK START
      // variable email needs to be fixed. It gets the column of values. 
      // it needs to be converted to a comma separated list of recepients
      var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange(1, 1, 100).getValues();
      // CHECK END

      var rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,15).getValues();
      sendEmail(email,rData);
       }
       else if(promptResponse == ui.Button.Close){
         var clear = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 6;
         clear.clearNote();
         return;
       }
      }
```

I have tried multiple variations on this but no luck. Any advice would be grwatful.

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the solution. It was so simple, just didn't see the forest through the trees. Basically in the ui.Button.CLOSE I has the Close with a capital and lowercase letters. Once I changed it to CLOSE my script worked great.

Final script:

```
    function sendMailEdit(e) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var rData1 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 15).getValues();
  var lj1 = rData1[0][0];
  
  if (sh.getName() == 'Design Doc Queue' && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.value == "Submitted") {
    var alertPromptText = '⚠️ Are you sure you want to submitt these drawings ' + lj1 + ' for review? ';
    var promptResponse = ui.alert(alertPromptText, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO_CANCEL);
    if (promptResponse == ui.Button.YES) {
      var email = e.source.getSheetByName("Email").getRange(1, 1, 1).getValues().flat().join(",");
      var rData = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 15).getValues();
      sendEmail(email, rData);
    } else if (promptResponse == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      clear();
    } else if (promptResponse == ui.Button.NO) {
      clear();
    } else if (promptResponse == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      clear();
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
    function clear() {
  var sheet, dateSheet, activeCell, activeRow;
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  dateSheet = "Design Doc Queue";
  activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  activeRow = activeCell.getRow();
  
  if(sheet.getName() === dateSheet && activeCell.getColumn() === 6 && activeCell.getDisplayValue() === "Submitted"){
    sheet.getRange(activeRow,6).clear({contentsOnly: true}).clearNote();
  } 
  
}
```

Thank you so much for your time.

D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var rData1 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 15).getValues();
  var lj1 = rData1[0][0];
  if (sh.getName() == 'Design Doc Queue' && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.value == "Submitted") {
    var alertPromptText = '⚠️ Are you sure you want to submitt these drawings ' + lj1 + ' for review? ';
    var promptResponse = ui.alert(alertPromptText, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO_CANCEL);
    if (promptResponse == ui.Button.YES) {
      var email = e.source.getSheetByName("Email").getRange(1, 1, 100).getValues().flat().join(",");
      var rData = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 15).getValues();
      sendEmail(email, rData);
    } else if (promptResponse == ui.Button.Close) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So if I hit close, the word submitted will remain in the cell at the drop down. I want the cell to reset to no words after I hit close, Just the blank drop down.

Comment: Okay now  now column 6 of the current will be set to blank

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. The cell remained with the word submitted, but there are no errors also. This should be associated with the active cell as this drop down is used in the same column but many rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you because I loose my short term memory of the problem after 14 hours of no response.    onEdits can be time consuming to debug.  I use e.source.toast() and Logger.log() a lot so I'd recommend that you dive into it and fix it yourself.  I'll be glad to help you if you need it but doing it for you does not seem to be working for me.